# Using Remmina with VPN

Tags: vpn, remmina

I've been looking for a way to use Remmina over a VPN connection which I have already configured. VPN connection works properly, but I'd like to remotely access the Windows computer in a lab, and would like to use Remmina. Could somebody give/link me a step-by-step tutorial for doing so?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly the machine must have a static IP address or some sort of [DDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) setup running so that the address will be static and won't change. Once that is confirmed you can follow the instructions below.

1. Open Remmina and select the New Connection icon.
   [image: Default Remmina Main Window(no connections)]
2. Then enter:

   - Name: the name for the connection
   - Server: the ip/dyn-dns address of the machine
   - Username: the username of the user account you would like to use to access the machine.
   - Password: the password for the account

     [image: Remmina Connection Settings Window]
3. Click Save
4. Select the connection and then click the Connect icon.
   [image: Remmina Main window with connection]

Comment: Thanks for such an informative answer! One question though : how is this using VPN?

Comment: There should be no need to do anything specific for the vpn. If you use the ip address of the machine you want to access it should work fine, as long as the VPN and routing is set up correctly.

Comment: Does this solution work?